# Don't show the "Edit Summary" field the first time a post is edited within the grace period

Tags: feature-request, editing, revisions

When you edit a post within the 5 minutes period, the new edit is not considered a new edit, and a new revision is not created.
If you just created a post, and then you edit it before 5 minutes are passed, the post appears as if you only created it. This means that the content of the "Edit Summary" field is not used; the field should not be shown in that case, as it is asking to the users something that is not even used.

Comment: What are you exactly asking here?

Comment: @Chaos It's a feature request. The title is the request, the body is the explanation.

Comment: @simchona huh. Not bad feature request.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the break in consistency would be worth the extra code here. It doesn't *hurt* to have the field present for rapid 5 minute grace period edits, and not having it might lead to confusion about why it is, and sometimes is not, present.

Comment: About leading to confusion, that could also be said for the "it doesn't belong here" that sometimes is present in the flag dialog box, and sometimes no. Also in that case, it has been used code to change the behavior already implemented, which is showing the closing dialog box also to users who already voted to close a question. I guess that in the case of the revision field, I can take that when it is empty, it is the first revision I made in the grace period.